# Bash Script not looping correctly

Tags: git, bash

I don't know anything about bash scripting. I have written this script to update all the repositories that I have in my directory. But instead of going through all the repos like it should, it is going through the first repository only and looping on the first one. What is the error in the code that is causing it ?

Code :

```
rm -rf log.txt
touch log.txt
ls > log.txt
for (( i = 0; i < $(cat log | wc -l); i++ )); do
    dir_name=$(sed "${i+1}q;d" log.txt)
    cd ${dir_name}
    git pull origin master
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Why such a convoluted way? `for dir_name in *; do ( cd "$dir_name"; git pull origin master ); done` is all it takes *and* is posix.

Comment: Thanks for this. As I said, I dont know bash scripting, I just picked up what  I thought I needed from other questions and pasted it into a somwhat working code:)

Comment: Problem is, that shell is *very different* from whatever language you are used to. Doing arithmetic in it is rare and almost never needed.

Comment: `log` and `log.txt` are different files-- this ain't Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> rm -rf log.txt
> touch log.txt
> ls > log.txt
> ```

There is rarely good reason to create temporary files in bash. Simple script like this should be able to handle everything with piping—or even better, just filename generation.

> ```
> for (( i = 0; i < $(cat log | wc -l); i++ )); do
> ```

This is a really, really, rare and obscure way to do loop in bash. Normal loop is

```
for variable in words…; do …; done
```

In this case, you don't need `ls` at all, because shell can generate list of files itself via filename generation. So just:

```
for dir_name in *; do
```

If you use a variable or shell expansion, it will be split, but on whitespace. You can pipe into a while loop for other splitting (see below).

> ```
>     dir_name=$(sed "${i+1}q;d" log.txt)
> ```

We've replaced this line by directly iterating over the names. But I should note, that *this* line is the reason why your original code didn't work (besides the missing extension). The problem is that

```
${variable+value}
```

is **not** an arithmetic expression. Instead, it returns `value` if `variable` is defined and nothing otherwise. So `${i+1}` is **always** `1`.

Arithmetic expression is instead written with `$(())`.

> ```
>     cd ${dir_name}
> ```

Normally the `{}` are only used if you need to delimit the variable name from the following text. However, what you *should* do is quote the expansion, because the directory name *might* include spaces and then the shell would split the name and the command would fail—or worse, do something dangerous! So

```
cd "$dir_name"
```

> ```
>     git pull origin master
>     cd ..
> ```

If the `cd "$dir_name"` fails for some reason, the `cd ..` will take you somewhere you didn't want to be:

- if `$dir_name` is a file, the first `cd` won't do anything and the second will take you one level up and
- if `$dir_name` is a symlink, the first `cd` will resolve it and the second will take you to parent of the actual directory.

I would normally use a subshell here:

```
(
    cd "$dir_name"
    git pull origin master
)
```

The `()` create a subshell. All changes made to variables and current directory are local to that block.

Alternately, you can use `pushd` and `popd`:

```
pushd "$dir_name"
git pull origin master
popd
```

but that requires a bash, while the rest of what I am writing here is POSIX shell. Writing shells without the bash extensions is good, because many systems have a POSIX shell under `/bin/sh`, that is faster than `bash`, but does not have most of those extensions.

> ```
> done
> ```

---

I mentioned a while loop. If you did want to generate the values by a program that outputs one per line, instead of a `for` loop you'd pipe into a `while` loop. So if you wanted to use `ls` here (there is no good reason to), you'd replace the `for` line with:

```
ls | while read -r dir_name; do
```

The `read` command reads a line from input and sets the specified variable to it (and fails when there is no line to read). The `while` then runs until the command fails. The `-r` flag tells it not to interpret `\` escape sequences. I don't remember off the top of my head whether the escaping mode of `ls` would match what `read` expects—if yes, that would be more reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is quite convoluted, instead you can try:

```
for dir_name in "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d)"; do
    cd "$dir_name" && git pull origin master && cd - || break
done
```

**EDIT** (handling whitespaces **correctly**):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir_name; do
    ( cd "$dir_name" && git pull origin master ) || break
done
```

In case not all directories are git repositories you can use this:

```
for dir_name in "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d)"; do
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir_name; do
    (
    cd "$dir_name" || exit $?
    [ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)" == "true" ] ||
        { echo "$dir_name: not a git repository"; exit 0; }
    git pull origin master || exit $?
    ) || break
done
```

Comment: It is good that you use `find` to filter directories only, but it can be either done more easily with `test`; or if you use `find`, at least use it correctly with `-print0 | while read -0` to avoid splitting on spaces!

Comment: I also don't think the `||` break is correct. It will *break* the loop when one of the directories is not a git repo and that does *not* seem to be the intention.

Comment: @JanHudec _break on spaces_: did you try it? The quotes around the find and the variable are there for this exact reason.

Comment: @JanHudec Judging by the look of the original script I do not think there are anything but git repository to be found, nonetheless, I shall edit the answer for completeness.

Comment: … oh, I completely missed the quotes! This is **not going to work at all**.

Comment: @JanHudec can you develop please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142885/discussion-between-silel-and-jan-hudec).

Answer (score 0):

cat 'log.txt' instead of 'log'

```
rm -rf log.txt
touch log.txt
ls > log.txt
for (( i = 1; i <= $(cat log.txt | wc -l); i++ )); do
    dir_name=$(sed "${i}q;d" log.txt)
    cd ${dir_name}
    git pull origin master
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed that but it still is looping on the first repo.

Comment: cat log | wc -l is likely returning 1 as in 'no file named log' is the 1 line. so it is only looking at the first line of log.txt

Comment: weird... let me run this thing real quick

Comment: I changed that to log.txt, ensured that log.txt is present and that it has all the names of the `dir` present, and also checked if the code can read the log.txt file. Still an error

Comment: @nivesnine _cat log | wc -l is likely returning 1 as in 'no file named log' is the 1 line_, this is doubtful, ls prints on stderr so wc will return 0 on error.

Comment: its mad about the i+1 part, just set i = 1; i <= $(cat log.txt | wc -l); i++ and change dir_name=$(sed "${i}q;d" log.txt)

Comment: Won't s/he miss the first line? If you want to use `i + 1`, you have to write `$((i + 1))`.

Comment: it starts at line 1, not 0. i + 1 when i = 0 would have the same outcome as i and i = 1

Answer (score -1):

Here is another possible approach.

```
ls -F | grep -e "/$" | while read repo
do
    git --git-dir=${repo}.git pull origin master
done
```

Comment: [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) isn't a great idea...

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for your share. I read the link and learn a lot. But in this case I think `ls` is fine. It's quite rare, at least I have never seen, that a git repository has a weird local directory name. This is a small script to do a small task. It does not have to be great. But of course we had better always to take as many exceptions into consideration as possible.

Comment: I hear you, regarding this being a small controlled situation. And I agree that at times, best practices can be ignored when safety and risk permit. But in this case, it seems to me it would be easier to use `for repo in */; do git --git-dir="${repo%/}.git" pull origin master; done`. Smaller command line, no pipes, zero risk.

Comment: @ghoti yes, it's much better. Thanks!